# java3d in android

Tags: java, android, java-3d

Hi all i'm new with android but i wonder if a java 3d application run on adk?
and run in the emulator?

Ciao
giovanni

Answer (score 2):

There's no Java 3D API available for Android. In fact, you're better off porting the application to use OpenGL directly for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Java 3D 1.6 is still maintained but it requires AWT which isn't available under Android and we don't plan to support it under Android in the future. Feel free to use JOGL 2, which supports both desktop environments and embedded environments (especially Android). If you look for a similar API supporting Android, JMonkeyEngine and LibGDX are worth a try. [JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Ardor3D_Tutorial) doesn't support Android yet.